# How to skip multiple header lines in CSV files with pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a text file that has several lines of header starting with `#`. How I can skip these lines using `pyspark`?

Is there any `lines.startswith` in `pyspark`?

Answer (score 0):

As given in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv), there exists a parameter `comment` which can be set to `#` to skip lines starting with this character.

Example,

```
df = sql.read.csv(path, comment="#", inferSchema=True, header=True)
```